# YouCompleteMe C++ semantic completion does not work for . operator

Tags: macvim, plugin-you-complete-me, filetype-c++

For the majority of Semantic triggers in C++ YCM works fine, but I've been unable to make it work for the `.` operator on a type. (For example, for a vector type I'd like to have the list of its available methods)

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0zTuAMfBU0) illustrates my point above.

Since I haven't found a single user of YCM complain about this problem, I assume there's a way to fix it via config I hope.

In case you need it, [this is what my .vimrc file looks like](https://gist.github.com/jlstr/167a825a47c656002dcf3944e41b6b14)

Does this have something to do with the **.ycm_extra_conf.py**? (which I have no idea how to configure)

Regards,
-J

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, I generate mine with:

```
cd ~/dotfiles/bundles/YCM-Generator
./config_gen.py -v -b cmake \
   --qt-version 5           \
   --configure_opts='-DQT_DIR=/opt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/gcc_64' \
   ~/workspace/my_source_directory
```

(QT is obviously unique to my needs, but I left it in as an example of how to add the CMake options)

This will place `.ycm_extra_conf.py` file into your source directory.